# Custom PMD rules for finding out method usages

Tags: sonarqube, pmd

Recently, we were trying to write a PMD rule to spot all occurances of Spring JDBC template's query* methods. Looking at some sample AST xml code, I wrote the following innocuous XPATH expression.

//PrimaryPrefix[Name[starts-with(@Image,'jdbcTemplate.query')]]

But very soon, we realized that this is not adequate. If someone writes "this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject" then "this" becomes the "Primary Prefix" and "jdbcTemplate" becomes the "Suffix". Also the variable name of the JDBCTemplate object instance could be anything.

I thought it would be fairly easy to construct a XPATH expression to find out the occurance of a particular Class method call - anywhere in the code, but looking at the AST tree, I am just not able to figure it out. Is a XPATH really possible, or we have to write Java code?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the Sonar [architectural rules engine](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Architecture+Rule+Engine) to find this kind of violation.

Comment: Sonar could be an option, but I am baffled by the fact that we cannot have something so simple expressed as a XPath in PMD ruleset. After all, I am just looking for a way to spot occurances of a objects method call.

Comment: @NarendraNaidu You tagged the question as "Sonar" didn't you? PMD rule extensions must be installed on the Sonar server (so that the build plugin can download them at runtime). Far simpler to use the Architectural rules engine for this type of constraint. It's what the feature is designed to support after all! Additionally you get a GUI to edit the rule.

Comment: Thanks. I do agree with you that writing the rule thru a graphical UI is much simpler. But currently Sonar Architecture rules only supports giving a package or class name. I could not find an option to specify a specific method/s. For e.g. I only want to mark all JdbcTempalte query* methods.